# XMLHttpRequest methods order is important?

Tags: javascript, flash, xmlhttprequest, call, onreadystatechange

This code works fine:

```
function callFromFlex(url, method, payload) {
   console.log("call from Flex: " + method + " " + url + " " + payload);
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open(method, url, true);
   xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xhttp.readyState);
       if (xhttp.readyState == 4) { 
        console.log("trying to call flash...");
           // Callback to Flash here
           ...  
       }
   };

   xhttp.send(payload);
}
```

But this does not - onreadystatechange is never called:

```
function callFromFlex(url, method, payload) {
    console.log("call from Flex: " + method + " " + url + " " + payload);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(xhttp.readyState);
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {    
            console.log("trying to call flash...");
            // Callback to Flash here;
            ... 
        }
    };
    xhttp.open(method, url, true);
    xhttp.send(payload);
}
```

I just moved xhttp.open(method, url, true) to another position and xhttp.onreadystatechange is never called. Checked with Firefox 45.0.2 and IE 11 and I believe it has nothing to do with the Flash player. The order shouldn't affect all this, should it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method order is absolutely important with XMLHttpRequest. The [description of `open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()) starts with:

> Initializes a request. This method is to be used from JavaScript code; to initialize a request from native code, use openRequest() instead.

Until `open` has been called, the request is not fully initialized (allocation *is not* initialization, here) and the other methods are not guaranteed to work correctly.

From some of [the examples in the WhatWG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method), `onreadystatechange` ought to work, but I can't imagine `setRequestHeader` will. In fact, calling `setRequestHeader` before `open` should throw an [`InvalidStateError`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM4Core/#invalidstateerror), [it seems](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader):

> If the state is not OPENED, throw an "InvalidStateError" exception.

Comment: OK, so I can set the request header on the "opened" XMLHttpRequest only. Weird.